# Sort numpy string array with negative numbers?

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, numpy

I'm having a problem sorting a numpy array that has numbers as strings.  I need to keep these as strings because there are other words after the integers.

It's sorting negative numbers in reverse order:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array(["3", "-2", "-1", "0", "2"])
>>> a.sort()
>>> a
array(['-1', '-2', '0', '2', '3'], dtype='|S2')
```

I would have expected the output to be:

```
array(['-2', '-1', '0', '2', '3'], dtype='|S2')
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: So you are keeping two types of data in a single string?  Doesn't seem particularly suited to `numpy`.

Comment: "I need to keep these as strings because there are other words after the integers". So you have a string like `"76 trombones"`, and you want to treat it like the number `76` followed by the word `"trombones"`? **Then do that**. Parse the strings and create 2-tuples of (number, rest of string).

Comment: No, it's not well-behaved.  Sometimes it's a number and string, sometimes it's just a string.  The "natural sorting" approach works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [natural sorting](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/200712/human_sorting.html):

```
import numpy as np
import re

def atoi(text):
    try:
        return int(text)
    except ValueError:
        return text

def natural_keys(text):
    '''
    alist.sort(key=natural_keys) sorts in human order
    http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/200712/human_sorting.html
    '''    
    return [ atoi(c) for c in re.split('([-]?\d+)', text) ]

a = np.array(["3", "-2", "-1", "0", "2", "word"])
print(sorted(a,key=natural_keys))
# ['-2', '-1', '0', '2', '3', 'word']

a = np.array(["3", "-2", "-1", "0", "2", "word", "-1 word", "-2 up"])
print(sorted(a,key=natural_keys))
# ['-2', '-2 up', '-1', '-1 word', '0', '2', '3', 'word']
```

Comment: That will get the wrong order if you try sort `["-1 word", "-2 up"]`, which is what I think the OP meant by "other words after the integers".

Comment: I posted the output when the array contains `["-1 word", "-2 up"]`. I think the order is correct, no?

Comment: You're right. I misread your regex. Looks good to me, depending on how you want to handle the case where no integer appears at the beginning of a string! (Mine raises a ValueError.)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming there's a space after the integer before the other words, then if `a` were a regluar python `list` you'd do:

```
a.sort(key = lambda s: int(s.split()[0]))
```

Not sure what the equivalent is in numpy (don't see how to specify a key), but one possibility is to convert to a list and back to an array.

Comment: Your version works with `sorted(a, key = lambda s: int(s.split()[0]))`.  Thanks!