# Sort alphanumeric strings in numpy matrix

Tags: python, sorting, matrix, numpy, alphanumeric

I have a matrix with 10 columns of different types. I sorted them based on the alphanumeric column with :

```
data = np.sort(data, axis=0,order='AlphaNumColumn')
```

It didn't do the job right, i.e.

```
BFT_job10_q0
BFT_job13_q0
BFT_job13_q1
BFT_job1_q0
```

instead of :

```
BFT_job1_q0
BFT_job10_q0
BFT_job13_q0
BFT_job13_q1
```

Anything numpy could do about it?? Thanks!

Comment: Related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7638738/sort-numpy-string-array-with-negative-numbers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sorting order seems to be right. I would recommend you to review your numbering:

```
1 becomes 01
```

If you have to keep your numbering, you can also do:

```
key = lambda x: '.'.join(x.split('_')[1:3]).replace('job','').replace('q','')

a[np.argsort([float(key(i)) for i in a[:,0]])]
```

Where `key()` will do the following:

```
key('BFT_job10_q0') --> 10.
key('BFT_job1_q0')  --> 1.
key('BFT_job13_q1') --> 13.1
key('BFT_job13_q0') --> 13.
```

Comment: Thanks, nicely thought through! Problem is, I have to keep the names as they are, as it is important for  downstream work... So I could use key() after sorting to place the removed name parts back in place -and I'll do that, so thanks again-, but is there any way we could easily get an alphanumeric sort?

Comment: Don't worry. the names are kept as they are. I just showed you how `key()` is working. But this function is used only for sorting, without changing the original values...

Comment: Hi, again. I feel helpless. I've tried to adapt your code to a new set of names, but I can't seem to find the way to do it. Data is typically the same as before, but this time, there's a little more: BFT_job10_q0_type0 etc. Your code doesn't work as a number with 2 decimals is not a float anymore...