# Sorting numpy matrix for a given column

Tags: python, numpy, sorting, matrix

I've tried to use Ned Batchelder code to sort in human order a `NumPy` matrix, as it was proposed in this following post:

[Sort numpy string array with negative numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7638738)

The code runs on a one-dimensional array, the command being:

```
print (sorted(a, key=natural_keys))
```

Now, my problem is that my data is a 10 column matrix and I want to sort it according to one column (let's say `MyColumn`). I can't find a way to modify the code to print the whole matrix sorted according to this very column. All I could come up with is this:

```
print (sorted(a['MyColumn'], key=natural_keys))
```

But, of course, only `MyColumn` shows up in the output, although it is correctly sorted...

**Is there a way to print the whole Matrix?**

Here is the command I used to load my array (I simplified my original imputfile to a 3 column array):

```
data = np.loadtxt(inputfile, dtype={'names': ('ID', 'MyColumn', 'length'),
'formats': ('int32', 'S40', 'int32')},skiprows=1, delimiter='\t')

ID  MyColumn    length
164967  BFT_job13_q1_type2  426
197388  BFT_job8_q0_type2   244
164967  BFT_job13_q0_type1  944
72406   BFT_job1_q0_type3   696
```

Here is what the output would ideally look like:

```
ID  MyColumn    length
72406   BFT_job1_q0_type3   696
197388  BFT_job8_q0_type2   244
164967  BFT_job13_q0_type1  944
164967  BFT_job13_q1_type2  426
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a `np.matrix`, called `m`:

```
col = 1
m[np.array(m[:,col].argsort(axis=0).tolist()).ravel()]
```

If you have a `np.ndarray`, called `a`:

```
col = 1
a[a[:,col].argsort(axis=0)]
```

If you have a structured array with named columns:

```
def mysort(data, col_name, key=None):
    d = data.copy()
    cols = [i[0] for i in eval(str(d.dtype))]
    if key:
        argsort = np.array([key(i) for i in d[col_name]]).argsort()
    else:
        argsort = d[col_name].argsort()
    for col in cols:
        d[col] = d[col][argsort]
    return d
```

For your specific case you need [the following `key` function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17378150/832621):

```
def key(x):
    x = ''.join([i for i in x if i.isdigit() or i=='_'])
    return '{1:{f}{a}10}_{2:{f}{a}10}_{3:{f}{a}10}'.format(*x.split('_'), f='0', a='>')

d = mysort(data, 'MyColumn', key)
```

Comment: Thanks. Still can't sort it right... 1-says "IndexError: too many indices" pointing at [:,col] 2- I changed [:,col] to [:][col] and it seems to do the job, but I don't know where to insert key=natural_keys to sort it the right way.

Comment: I might add... I don't know how to check whether I have a np.ndarray or a np.matrix! I loaded a text file with np.loadtxt

Comment: you have a `np.ndarray` when loading with `np.loadtxt()`

Comment: @Sara It should work you don't need `natural_keys`... you just have to inform which column you want to sort using `col`, remembering that `0` is the 1st column

Comment: Yes, I did it so. And, as a matter of fact, 'MyColumn' is the second one of my array, so col = 1 should work. Would it help if I add that 'MyColumn' is made up of alphanumeric values? As I said, compiler says "IndexError: too many indices" if I run your line. now if I run this **m[np.array(m[:][1].argsort(axis=0).tolist()).ravel()]**, it extract the first row of my array. If I change it to  **m[np.array(m[:]['MyColum'].argsort(axis=0).tolist()).ravel()]** it sorts it, but the usual way...

Comment: I think she has a structured array, so they aren't properly columns, but fields.

Comment: @Sara Now that Jaime made it clear the type of array that you have and with your question update it was possible to propose another solution, please check the updated answer...

Comment: @sgpc I used the command `d = mysort (data,'MyColumn')`. It sorted the array all right, but it sorted it the usual way i.e. exactly what the input was, no change at all. I'll update and show what would make me happy ;)

Comment: @sgpc Thanks for your time, but it still doesn't sort it right... I put another set of data above, and on this set, *BFT_job8_q0_type2* ends up at the end of the list instead of the second place. I changed your code a little just to include *type* : `key = lambda x: '.'.join(x.split('_')[1:4]).replace('job','').replace('q','').replace('type','')`

Comment: @sgpc Hey thank you very much indeed. It doesn't work for larger 'job' number, but I believe I can work my way through with what you've already given :) Cheers!

Comment: for large job numbers just use a higher number of more digits in the formatting string, like `'{1:{f}{a}10}_{2:{f}{a}10}_{3:{f}{a}10}'`... which can handle a job number up to `9999999999`